# Anaconda won't activate virtual environment

Tags: syntax-error, windows-10, anaconda, environment, activation

I know similar problems have already been adressed, but I just couldn't find the solution in the previous answers that were given...
So here's the thing : I created an environment using

```
conda create -n djangodev pyhton=3.4
```

I checked, and the folder is created in \Anaconda3\envs but when I want to activate it :

```
activate djangodev
```

I get :

```
  File "<ipython-input-71-d6d1f1bb5b1c>", line 1
activate djangodev
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I really don't know what to do. I tried changing the path but I couldn't find how to do it properly, as all the ways I've tried didn't work.
Could you help me please ?
Thanks !

Comment: I am pretty sure conda environments silently fail on Windows 10. Sadly I can't test right now, or I'd post a more complete answer. I don't think I've ever seen a SyntaxError though...but the support is not good for Windows, I can safely say that

Comment: so I should try on Linux or something like that ?

Comment: I've had better luck on linux. if you have access to a linux box, definitely give it a try there. If you don't, I'd suggest just staying away from conda envs. You don't *actually* need them to develop working software. All other features of Anaconda seem to work well on Windows

Comment: @Bartoche you have typo in `conda create -n djangodev pyhton=3.4` should be `python=3.4`